# MySQL INSERT multiple rows if certain values don't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which works correctly:

```
INSERT INTO Events (user_ID, event_type, event_creation_datetime, unit_ID)
SELECT 10, 'user_other_unit_moved', now(), 8383
FROM Events
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT event_ID FROM Events WHERE event_type = 'user_other_unit_moved' AND unit_ID = 8383)
LIMIT 1;
```

What the query does is check to see if a row exists in my Events table that matches the event type and unit ID I wish to INSERT. If it finds an existing record, it does not proceed with the INSERT. However, if it does not find a record then it proceeds with the INSERT.

This is the structure of my Events table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Events` (
  `event_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_type` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `event_creation_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `unit_ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Events`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`event_ID`),
  ADD KEY `unit_ID` (`unit_ID`);

ALTER TABLE `Events`
  MODIFY `event_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

The problem I have is trying to get the above query to work correctly when trying to INSERT multiple rows. I know how to INSERT multiple rows using comma delimited VALUES, but no matter what I try I get syntax errors. Here is the query I have been playing with:

```
INSERT INTO Events (user_ID, event_type, event_creation_datetime, unit_ID)
VALUES (
(SELECT 10, 'user_other_unit_moved', now(), 8383
FROM Events
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT event_ID FROM Events WHERE event_type = 'user_other_unit_moved' AND unit_ID = 8383)
 LIMIT 1)),
(SELECT 10, 'user_other_unit_moved', now(), 8380
FROM Events
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT event_ID FROM Events WHERE event_type = 'user_other_unit_moved' AND unit_ID = 8380)
 LIMIT 1))
);
```

However, no matter what I try (inserting, removing parentheses etc.) I get either the generic "You have an error in your SQL syntax;" or "Operand should contain only 1 column".

I have also tried this alternative based on other StackOverflow posts:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Events (event_ID, user_ID, event_type, event_creation_datetime, unit_ID)
VALUES
(SELECT (SELECT event_ID FROM Events WHERE event_type = 'user_other_unit_moved' AND unit_ID = 8383), 10, 'user_other_unit_moved', now(), 8383),
(SELECT (SELECT event_ID FROM Events WHERE event_type = 'user_other_unit_moved' AND unit_ID = 8383), 10, 'user_other_unit_moved', now(), 8383);
```

But this fails with "Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause" even if I try to return results using temporary tables.

Is it just an error with my syntax, or am I trying to do something not possible with the way my query is laid out? And if it's just an error, how would I write the query so that it works as I've intended? Note that I do not want to use multi-queries - I want the query to work as one statement.

Thanks,
Arj

Comment: It's always useful to include table definitions so that we can see the keys you have in place. That way we can say if using INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY is appropriate.

Comment: have you read about [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) this may help. Thanks!

Comment: Good point about the table definition. I've updated my post to include the fact that event_ID is the PK (nothing else about the table is relevant).

Comment: Yes, I did read about INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE which gave me the idea for the second version of my query. However, this doesn't work due to using a SELECT ... FROM from the same table I'm INSERTing into.

Comment: Is the PK AUTO_INCREMENT? If not you must supply a value.

Comment: Apologies, yes the PK is AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: I think it's a mistake to lecture the SO community on what is and isn't relevant. If it's in the question/query, then it's relevant. If it's not relevant, then it shouldn't appear anywhere within the question/query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `VALUES`, just `INSERT ... SELECT` and **not** `FROM events`.
Then `UNION ALL`.
This code works for **MySql 5.6**:

```
INSERT INTO Events (user_ID, event_type, event_creation_datetime, unit_ID)
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 10 user_ID, 'user_other_unit_moved' event_type, 
    now() event_creation_datetime, 8383 unit_ID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 'user_other_unit_moved', now(), 8380
) t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Events e 
  WHERE e.event_type = t.event_type AND e.unit_ID = t.unit_ID
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jX9Qp6PGFMQv1oKp7N3rPY/6).
This code works for **MySql 5.7+**:

```
INSERT INTO Events (user_ID, event_type, event_creation_datetime, unit_ID)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 10, 'user_other_unit_moved', now(), 8383
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Events WHERE event_type = 'user_other_unit_moved' AND unit_ID = 8383)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 'user_other_unit_moved', now(), 8380
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Events WHERE event_type = 'user_other_unit_moved' AND unit_ID = 8380)
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jX9Qp6PGFMQv1oKp7N3rPY/1)
And this for **MySql 8.0+**:

```
INSERT INTO Events (user_ID, event_type, event_creation_datetime, unit_ID)
SELECT 10, 'user_other_unit_moved', now(), 8383
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Events WHERE event_type = 'user_other_unit_moved' AND unit_ID = 8383)
UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'user_other_unit_moved', now(), 8380
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Events WHERE event_type = 'user_other_unit_moved' AND unit_ID = 8380);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jX9Qp6PGFMQv1oKp7N3rPY/4).

Answer (score 1):

Although you can write this with just `union all`:

```
INSERT INTO Events (user_ID, event_type, event_creation_datetime, unit_ID)
    SELECT x.user_id, x.event_type, now(), x.unit_id
    FROM (SELECT 10 as user_id, 8383 as unit_id, 'user_other_unit_moved' as event_type
         ) x
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Events e2 WHERE e2.event_type = x.event_type AND e2.unit_ID = x.unit_ID)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x.user_id, x.event_type, now(), x.unit_id
    FROM (SELECT 10 as user_id, 8380 as unit_id, 'user_other_unit_moved' as event_type
         ) x
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Events e2 WHERE e2.event_type = x.event_type AND e2.unit_ID = x.unit_ID);
```

I suspect there is a better way.  If a `unit_id` can have only one row for each event type, then you should specify that using a unique constraint or index:

```
create unique constraint unq_events_unit_id_event_type on events(unit_id, event_type);
```

It is better to have the database ensure integrity.  In particularly, your version is subject to race conditions.  And to duplicates being inserted within the same statement.

Then you can use `on duplicate key` to prevent duplicate rows:

```
INSERT INTO Events (user_ID, event_type, event_creation_datetime, unit_ID)
    VALUES (10, 'user_other_unit_moved', now(), 8383),
           (10, 'user_other_unit_moved', now(), 8380)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE unit_ID = VALUES(unit_ID);
```

The update actually does nothing (because `unit_ID` already has that value).  But it does prevent an error and a duplicate row from being inserted.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I've tried your first solution before and it produces the same error, although given that a couple of you have suggested this now (and I've also used the same example from another SO post) I'm beginning to suspect that there may be something wrong with my configuration. By the way, I can't have a unique constraint as unit_IDs can have multiple rows with the same event_type. This is because it's a multi-player game, and units can be moved multiple times (for example).

Comment: @Arj . . . Good morning (where I am).  MySQL requires a `FROM` clause to use `WHERE`.  You can just add in `FROM dual`, but I prefer to list the values in a derived table so they don't have to be repeated in the `EXISTS` clause.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks very much - your edited answer is not presenting any syntax errors when I test it with EXPLAIN - so far so good. I will do a detailed test with some more code and report back with my results.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks very much for your help with this. I've awarded the answer to forpas as both your answers were effectively the same - I wish I could award answers to both of you!

Comment: @Arj . . . I think you missed the point of this answer.  You should be using a unique index/constraint to maintain data integrity.  (And I'll point out that I fixed the initial code so it works hours before forpas.)

Comment: Hi Gordon, my first comment was a response to your suggestion of using a constraint - it's not possible in my scenario because unit_IDs can have multiple identical event_type entries. I'm sorry, I didn't notice that your edited code was posted hours before forpas - what do you suggest I do?